# Discrepancy between linux grep and Ruby's scan results

Tags: ruby, regex, string, grep

I have a list of DNA sequences (one per line):

ACTGCTCGGGGG.....

CGCTCGCTTCTCTC...

etc

Most sequences contain two specific motifs, one close to the begining and one closer to the end. I am extracting the sequences inbetween:

1. with grep:  `grep "motif1.*motif2" inputfile > outputfile`
2. in ruby with scan, where `sequences` is an array of DNA sequences:

   ```
    sequences.each do |seq|
     tmp=seq.scan(/motif1.*motif2/)[0]
     outputfile << tmp if tmp
    end
   ```

The problem is I am getting different number of the extracted sequences.
Why?

Comment: What are you getting as output with each one?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ruby but I guess ruby may return matched parts only while grep doesn't by default? -- Anyway, try `grep -o "pattern" infile > outfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's `scan` returns an array with the matched regex parts, by default. Grep doesn't do that, it returns the whole line with the match highlighted if `color` is set to `auto`. To retrieve matched parts only from [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), use the `-o` option.

```
grep -o "motif1.*motif2" inputfile > outputfile
```

Previous command should save the same output as the [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)'s scan does.